# Python: Как реализовать алгоритм создания списков в словаре

Tags: алгоритм, list, словари

Из времени входа и выхода (попарно):

```
intervals = [
   {
     'lesson': [1594663200, 1594666800],
     'pupil':  [1594663340, 1594663389, 1594663390, 1594663395, 1594663396, 1594666472],
     'tutor':  [1594663290, 1594663430, 1594663443, 1594666473]
   }
            ]
```

Нужно чтобы создавался списки в словарях:
**0,1 : 0,1** ; **0,1 : 2,3** ; **2,3 : 0,1** ; **2,3 : 2,3**...

```
{
     'lesson': [1594663200, 1594666800],
     'pupil':  [1594663340, 1594663389],
     'tutor':  [1594663290, 1594663430]
}
```

```
{
     'lesson': [1594663200, 1594666800],
     'pupil':  [1594663340, 1594663389],
     'tutor':  [1594663443, 1594666473]
}
```

```
{
     'lesson': [1594663200, 1594666800],
     'pupil':  [1594663390, 1594663395],
     'tutor':  [1594663290, 1594663430]
}
```

```
{
     'lesson': [1594663200, 1594666800],
     'pupil':  [1594663390, 1594663395],
     'tutor':  [1594663443, 1594666473]
}
```

**...**

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то вы ходите сгенерировать все возможные варианты словарей таким образом, чтобы каждый ключ в итоге соответствовал паре разных элементов из изначального списка, соответствующего данному ключу? То есть из словаря {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c': [7, 8, 9]} вы бы получили (я опущу ключи) `{[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]}, {[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 9]}, {[1, 2], [4, 5], [8, 9]}, {[1, 2], [4, 6], [7, 8]}, {[1, 2], [4, 6], [7, 9]}, {[1, 2], [4, 6], [8, 9]}...`, верно?

Comment: Нет, там должны быть пара к паре ( в обоих списках четкое количество): пара_из _списка1 + пара_из_списка2 , пара_из_списка_1 + вторая_пара_из_списка2

Comment: Списки это время присутствия каждого пользователя в  виде интервалов

Comment: Можно через 2 - for пройти, но  не могу понять, как сделать, чтобы ,как идти именно пара к паре ( а не элемент к элементу)

Comment: У вас всегда три списка в словаре или их может быть любое число?

Comment: Простите, что так не понятно написал, нужны только pupil и tutor

Comment: списка  всегда   два

Comment: @DarMaster, кажется вы решаете эту задачу: [...найти пересечения времени](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1257076)? Если так, то вы заходите не с того конца.

Comment: Воу, а её даже не гуглил, но я уже сделал решил её для, матрицы 2*3, поэтому и перебираю столбцы, чтобы создать  такую, но большое вам спасибо, чужое решение всегда интересно !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тогда все очень просто: делаем два цикла, где внешний идет по парам 'pupil', а внутренний - по парам 'tutor':

```
ans = []
for i in range(0, len(intervals['pupil']), 2):
    for j in range(0, len(intervals['tutor']), 2):
        ans.append({'lesson': intervals['lesson'], \
                    'pupil':  intervals['pupil'][i:i+2], \
                    'tutor':  intervals['turor'][j:j+2] })
```

Comment: Большое спасибо,  а как загуглить, чтобы понять , что это [i:i+2]?

Comment: @DarMaster Стандартный синтаксис срезов в питоне). Я по привычке написал. Можно просто использовать `[intervals['tutor'][j], intervals['tutor'][j+1]]` вместо этого.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Длинный, но красивый и универсальный ответ. Работает для любого количества списков, не задействует ни одного цикла, может служить иллюстрацией для генераторов и модуля `itertools`.

План такой: разрезать все списки на пары, к спискам пар применить декартово произведение, его элементы преобразовать в словари.

Данные для работы:

```
task = {
    'lesson': [1594663200, 1594666800],
    'pupil': [1594663340, 1594663389, 1594663390, 1594663395, 1594663396, 1594666472],
    'tutor': [1594663290, 1594663430, 1594663443, 1594666473]
}
```

Режем список на пары. Это настоящая магия:

```
def pairs(iterable):
    return zip(*[iter(iterable)] * 2)
```

> ```
> @>>> print(*pairs(task['pupil']), sep='\n')
> (1594663340, 1594663389)
> (1594663390, 1594663395)
> (1594663396, 1594666472)
> ```

Режем все значения в словаре на помеченные пары:

```
def tagged_pairs(task):
    for k, v in task.items():
        yield tuple((k, p) for p in pairs(v))
```

> ```
> @>>> print(*tagged_pairs(task), sep='\n')
> (('lesson', (1594663200, 1594666800)),)
> (('pupil', (1594663340, 1594663389)), ('pupil', (1594663390, 1594663395)), ('pupil', (1594663396, 1594666472)))
> (('tutor', (1594663290, 1594663430)), ('tutor', (1594663443, 1594666473)))
> ```

Декартово произведение помеченных пар ([itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)):

> ```
> @>>> print(*itertools.product(*tagged_pairs(task)), sep='\n')
> (('lesson', (1594663200, 1594666800)), ('pupil', (1594663340, 1594663389)), ('tutor', (1594663290, 1594663430)))
> (('lesson', (1594663200, 1594666800)), ('pupil', (1594663340, 1594663389)), ('tutor', (1594663443, 1594666473)))
> (('lesson', (1594663200, 1594666800)), ('pupil', (1594663390, 1594663395)), ('tutor', (1594663290, 1594663430)))
> (('lesson', (1594663200, 1594666800)), ('pupil', (1594663390, 1594663395)), ('tutor', (1594663443, 1594666473)))
> (('lesson', (1594663200, 1594666800)), ('pupil', (1594663396, 1594666472)), ('tutor', (1594663290, 1594663430)))
> (('lesson', (1594663200, 1594666800)), ('pupil', (1594663396, 1594666472)), ('tutor', (1594663443, 1594666473)))
> ```

Элементы декартова произведения превращаем в словари:

```
def groups(task):
    return map(dict, itertools.product(*tagged_pairs(task)))
```

> ```
> @>>> print(*groups(task), sep='\n') 
> {'lesson': (1594663200, 1594666800), 'pupil': (1594663340, 1594663389), 'tutor': (1594663290, 1594663430)}
> {'lesson': (1594663200, 1594666800), 'pupil': (1594663340, 1594663389), 'tutor': (1594663443, 1594666473)}
> {'lesson': (1594663200, 1594666800), 'pupil': (1594663390, 1594663395), 'tutor': (1594663290, 1594663430)}
> {'lesson': (1594663200, 1594666800), 'pupil': (1594663390, 1594663395), 'tutor': (1594663443, 1594666473)}
> {'lesson': (1594663200, 1594666800), 'pupil': (1594663396, 1594666472), 'tutor': (1594663290, 1594663430)}
> {'lesson': (1594663200, 1594666800), 'pupil': (1594663396, 1594666472), 'tutor': (1594663443, 1594666473)}
> ```