# Python, Ошибка при подсчете

Tags: python

Задача на пересечение времени

— lesson – начало и конец урока

— pupil – интервалы присутствия ученика

— tutor – интервалы присутствия учителя

Интервалы устроены следующим образом – это всегда список из четного количества элементов. Под четными индексами (начиная с 0) время входа на урок, под нечетными - время выхода с урока. Нужно написать функцию, которая получает на вход словарь с интервалами и возвращает время общего присутствия ученика и учителя на уроке (в секундах).

Входные данные:

```
tests = [
    {'data': {'lesson': [1594663200, 1594666800],
              'pupil': [1594663340, 1594663389, 1594663390, 1594663395, 1594663396, 1594666472],
              'tutor': [1594663290, 1594663430, 1594663443, 1594666473]},
     'answer': 3117
     },
    {'data': {'lesson': [1594702800, 1594706400],
              'pupil': [1594702789, 1594704500, 1594702807, 1594704542, 1594704512, 1594704513, 1594704564, 1594705150,
                        1594704581, 1594704582, 1594704734, 1594705009, 1594705095, 1594705096, 1594705106, 1594706480,
                        1594705158, 1594705773, 1594705849, 1594706480, 1594706500, 1594706875, 1594706502, 1594706503,
                        1594706524, 1594706524, 1594706579, 1594706641],
              'tutor': [1594700035, 1594700364, 1594702749, 1594705148, 1594705149, 1594706463]},
     'answer': 3577
     },
    {'data': {'lesson': [1594692000, 1594695600],
              'pupil': [1594692033, 1594696347],
              'tutor': [1594692017, 1594692066, 1594692068, 1594696341]},
     'answer': 3565
     },
]
```

Ошибка при подсчете ответа 'answer': 3577

Сам код:

```
def appearance(intervals):
    lesson = intervals['lesson']
    pupil = intervals['pupil']
    tutor = intervals['tutor']
    lesson_range = range(lesson[0], lesson[1]+1)
    pupil_ranges = make_ranges(pupil)
    tutor_ranges = make_ranges(tutor)
    intervals_list = []
    check_list = []
    check_list += lesson
    check_list += pupil
    check_list += tutor
    for timestamp in check_list:
        if timestamp in lesson_range:
            pupil_result = check_in_range(timestamp, pupil_ranges)
            tutor_result = check_in_range(timestamp, tutor_ranges)
            if pupil_result == True and tutor_result == True:
                intervals_list.append(timestamp)
    intervals_list.sort()
    time = 0
    for i in range(1, len(intervals_list), 2):
        delta = intervals_list[i] - intervals_list[i-1]
        time += delta
    return time


def check_in_range(timestamp, ranges):
    for timedelta in ranges:
        if timestamp in timedelta:
            return True


def make_ranges(intervals):
    range_list = []
    for i in range(1, len(intervals), 2):
        range_list.append(range(intervals[i-1], intervals[i]+1))
    return range_list

def main():
    appearance(tests)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i, test in enumerate(tests):
        test_answer = appearance(test['data'])
        assert test_answer == test['answer'], f'Error on test case {i}, got {test_answer}, expected {test["answer"]}'
```

Comment: 1) где исполняемый код? Тут одни функции. 2) Какая именно ошибка, в чем вероятная причина?

Comment: @Сергей поправила, добавила функции исполнения, на счет ошибки не знаю, первые и последние данные считаются корректно

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=lesson+pupil+tutor

Comment: Как вы тестировали код?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy при несовпадении вылетает сообщение об ошибке, через debug прогоняла, но так и не поняла что идет не так

Comment: Ясно. Тогда рекомендую: 1) быть на 100% уверенной, что тест правильный, я тут вчера уже обнаружил неверный тест; 2) Уменьшить тест до нескольких значений и наращивать постепенно до появления сбоя, одновременно просчитывая вручную и сравнивая результаты. Учитывая, что разница между полученным значением и тестовым - в 9 раз (398 вместо 3577), а два других теста дают основной рост на последнем шаге, то, если получится посчитать вручную с конца, то лучше даже идти с конца, уменьшая тест по одному шагу . В этом тесте их десять: 7
19
48
65
217
303
313
314
322
398

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, спасибо. Так что я, вероятно, правильно предположил, что тест неверный. Вера, а вы где тесты взяли с результатами?

Comment: тем не менее, оставляю подозрение на неверность теста 2:-)

Comment: @Сергей, в тесте с индексом 1 некоторые отрезки присутствия ученика пересекаются между собой. Одно из моих решений предполагало что таких пересечений нет (что времена в списке не убывают). Это требование было нарушено. Я его учёл, первый тест - нормальный тест.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, я достаточно часто нахожу ответы на уровне интуитивных догадок. Я не анализировал тест 2, оставлю это Вере. Кстати, пересечение отрезков, на мой взгляд, тоже нарушение условия, в реальной жизни как такое может быть?

Comment: @Сергей, да, такое возможно, если учеников несколько, а для урока достаточного любого ученика. Это делает задачу ещё сложнее. Честно говоря, для неподготовленного человека эта задача слишком сложна.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, не представляю такие уроки. Это уже что-то из серии: "на урок пришло 1.5 ученика и 0.75 учителя. Сколько учителей будет заниматься с каждой 0.1 ученика? На какую оценку может рассчитывать 0.5 ученика, если это соревнования по прыжкам на скакалке?"

Comment: Уважаемая @VeraK списала решение отсюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1257734/416121. Это не правильное решение.

Answer (score 1):

Вот тест, который вам поможет. Урок и учитель начинаются и завершаются одновременно. Ученик исчезает с началом урока и появляется в его конце. Общее время - ноль (идеальная учебная ситуация). Ваша программа выводит единицу. Отлаживайтесь. Ошибка в алгоритме. Насколько я его понял - он совсем не рабочий. Но я мог и не понять:

```
{'data': {'lesson': [1, 2],
          'pupil': [0, 1, 2, 3],
          'tutor': [1, 2]},
 'answer': 0
}
```