# Объединить 2 массива

Tags: php, php7, php8

```
[1=>20, 30 => 40, 98 => 99]
[1=>5, 37 => 42, 80 => 99]
```

2 массива, каждый массив это отрезки, которые просмотрел пользователь в видео. Значения от 0 до 100

Где ключ - старт проигрывания, значение - окончание.

Возьмем первый

```
[1=>20, 30 => 40, 98 => 99]
```

Пользователь начал смотреть с 1 процента на 20%, перемотал на 30% и просмотрел до 40, затем с 98 по 99%

Вопрос каким образом, что за алгоритм, который будет обрабатывать быстро. Так как частота выполнения данной задачи высокая.

Необходимо 2 массива объединить и получить на выходе

```
    [1 => 20, 30 => 42, 80 => 99]

$m  = [1=>6, 8 => 11, 79 => 99];
$m1 = [0=>5, 11 => 45, 45 =>55, 80 => 95];

$s = 101;
for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++) {

  if(($m[$i] || $m1[$i]) && $s == 101) {
     $s = $i;
     $max = max($m[$i], $m1[$i]);
  }

  if($mm[$s] < $m[$i])
   $mm[$s] = $m[$i];

  if($mm[$s] < $m1[$i])
   $mm[$s] = $m1[$i];

  $max <= $i && $s = 101;

}

print_r($mm);
```

Ничего не получается...

Казалось что все работает

```
Array ( [0] => 6 [8] => 45 [45] => 55 [79] => 99 )

[8] => 45 [45] => 55
```

Должнно быть

```
8 => 55
```

Comment: Как я вижу: для начала сформировать множество (Set) чисел от 1 до N, которые входят в указанные промежутки всех массивов. Затем собрать новый массив попарно. Пара определяется когда следующее число не идёт последовательно за текущим

Comment: Можно пожалуйста пример. Ранее пытался реализовать это, но у меня какая та зацикленность получалась, что сервер ложился.

Comment: Да вроде итак ясно.... вначале set .... будет 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 и т.д. ...... сделать из всех массивов генерацию чисел тоже не вижу сложной. использовать цикл и  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

Comment: *Так как частота выполнения данной задачи высокая* - насколько высокая? там весь диапазон 0-100, как ни делай - это копейки

Comment: В какие та дебри залез, попытался что то похожее сделать, не выходит

Answer (score 1):

Сложите в массив пары, содержащие все временные отсчеты, а вторым элементом +1 для начала интервала, или -1 для конца. Отсортируйте по времени.

Теперь пройдите по массиву, добавляя к счётчику второй элемент пар. Если счетчик стал ненулевым - начался объединенный интервал, если обнулился - интервал кончился.

Если массивов всегда будет только два, то ещё проще - продвигаетесь по обоим массивам параллельно, выбирая минимальную из следующих временных отметок и соответственно меняя состояние.

Comment: Количество ключей(значений) в каждом массиве может быть разным.

Comment: Это не имеет значения. Подобно этапу слияния в сортировке mergesort, выбирается меньшее из последующих времён. Если у вас действительно ключ-значение, то это несколько неудобно организовывать, начала и концы должны быть однородны

Comment: Можно пример привести, не понимаю как толком это сделать...

Comment: Для вашего примера. Минимальное число 1, начался интервал счетчик 1.  Следующее тоже 1, это тоже начало, счетчик 2. Следующее 5, это конец, счетчик 1, следующее 20, это конец, счетчик 0, закончился интервал. Так же дальше 30 37 40 42 и т.д.

Comment: Ничего не понял

Comment: Все просто и легко, а сделать никто не может...

Comment: Я не знаю php настолько, чтобы правильно переформировать вашу организацию данных. Вот [пример на Питоне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1257076/python-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8/1257447#1257447) (правда, там требуется пересечение, а не объединение)